# why cppcheck report have no function name?

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I can set report format like "./cppcheck --template  {file}:{line},{severity},{id},{message}" to get more information, but can not get function name.

Is there any method?

Comment: Why do you need this informationen? The provided information (filename, line number, etc.)  is sufficient to identify each issue.

Comment: Because we also use some other static check tools, and i want to unify static check report format , other code check tools have function name in their report. So I wonder why cppcheck do not support this?

Comment: I recommend to get in touch with the cppcheck development team at https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/